# Facebook tab not loading due to HTTPS

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-apps

I built an app for facebook on my system and then planned to move it into shortstack so I could easily publish it to Facebook. Unfortunately, while everything loads correctly in shortstack, nothing loads on the Facebook page. I think this is due to mixing HTTP and HTTPS but I've never had my browser complain about this before so Im not sure what to do.

How can I either A) circumvent Facebooks HTTPS requirement so that my iframes load
or B) determine a different root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook apps must be served using HTTPS (unless they are in sandbox mode). That means you must get SSL certificate. You can get one for free from http://StartSSL.com for example - i have had only positive experience with them.